# Connectivity of a Hamiltonian path

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if G has a Hamiltonian path then for every proper subset S of V, $\,$ $\omega(G-S)\leq\vert S \vert + 1$,$\,$where V is the set of the  vertices of G and $\omega$ is the number of the components of G. (from Graph Theory With Applications, Bondy, Murty, 1976)

Comment: HINT* Think about how any Hamiltonian path could reach each of the $\omega(G-S)$ components from |S| if $\omega(G-S) > |S| + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $G$ has a Hamiltonian path $H$. Then, $\omega(G-S) \leq \omega(H - S)$. Can you bound the size of $\omega(H-S)$?

Comment: @Micheal: Not a clue.And I fail to see the reason why  ω(G−S)≤ω(H−S)

Comment: Take a path and remove $0$ vertices, and it remains in $1$ piece. Take a path and remove $1$ vertex, and it falls into $2$ pieces. Take a path and remove $2$ vertices, and it falls into at most $3$ pieces, etc...

Comment: To see $\omega(G-S) \leq \omega(H-S)$, note that adding edges to a graph cannot increase the number of connected components. $G-S$ and $H-S$ share the same vertex set, and $G-S$ contains every edge in $H-S$...